# Downloading XML-Security error

Tags: linux, make, configure, tomcat

I'm trying to download XML-security (2.0.4) on Linux (Amazon linux) in an effort to compile Shibboleth-SP. When I run the standard configure provided by the documentation (https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SP3/pages/2067398783/XML-Security-C) :

```
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp
```

I get an issue with the compiler trying to find xerces files since they are within my shibboleth directory. I then export the needed variables:

export xerces_LIBS=/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib
export xerces_CFLAGS=/opt/shibboleth-sp/include

I then use the configure again and it tells me it cannot find xercesdefs.hpp file
so I then updated my configure script to the following:

```
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include"
```

This gets me passed the error, however during the build I see "linker input file unused because linking not done....
g++: warning: /opt/shibboleth-sp/include: linker input file unused because linking not done. This is repeated per file until the compilation process completes.

```
mv -f xkms/impl/.deps/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSCompoundResultImpl.Tpo xkms/impl/.deps/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSCompoundResultImpl.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I.. -I.. -DXSEC_BUILDING_LIBRARY   /opt/shibboleth-sp/include   -pthread -I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include -MT xkms/impl/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.lo -MD -MP -MF xkms/impl/.deps/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.Tpo -c -o xkms/impl/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.lo `test -f 'xkms/impl/XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.cpp' || echo './'`xkms/impl/XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.. -DXSEC_BUILDING_LIBRARY /opt/shibboleth-sp/include -pthread -I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include -MT xkms/impl/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.lo -MD -MP -MF xkms/impl/.deps/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.Tpo -c xkms/impl/XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o xkms/impl/.libs/libxml_security_c_la-XKMSRevokeKeyBindingImpl.o
```

The configure process finished and when I use make I cannot proceed.

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.4'
Making all in xsec

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.4/xsec'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -W /opt/shibboleth-sp/include    -I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include   -o xsec-xtest tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o libxml-security-c.la /opt/shibboleth-sp/lib   -lcrypto
libtool: link: g++ -Wall -W /opt/shibboleth-sp/include -I/opt/shibboleth-sp/include -o .libs/xsec-xtest tools/xtest/xsec_xtest-xtest.o /opt/shibboleth-sp/lib  ./.libs/libxml-security-c.so -lpthread -lcrypto -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib
/opt/shibboleth-sp/include: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [xsec-xtest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.4/xsec'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/build/xml-security-c-2.0.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What file is it trying to find here? Is it an issue that linking is not done? I've been stumped for some time on this issue building XML-security, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not post image, post text!

Comment: I edited with text instead of pictures, sorry about that.

Comment: What you've copied isn't a standard configuration command, it's an example one. Follow the compilation instructions instead of the overview. [Compile Shibboleth SP from source on Linux (including dependencies)](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SP3/pages/2067400237/Compile+Shibboleth+SP+from+source+on+Linux+including+dependencies)

Comment: understood however running the command at the beginning still isnt getting xml security on my server. And I need to download xml-security. It still is not building.